# REST not working on Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, rest, tomcat

I have a simple WAR application offering a REST Service. I use RESTClient on the same Version of Firefox running on the same machine as the webservice. 
This works fine locally on a Tomcat 9.0.10 on Windows 10 Enterprise.
When I start the same application on a Windows Server 2016, which has exactly the same Tomcat running, I get a 404.
Locally accessing the tomcat Management page (http://localhost:8080) works fine. On both machines the same Version on Java 8 is installed.
Any ideas, what could be the reason for this behaviours are welcome …
Regards Claus

Comment: I disabled the complete Firewall Settings on the 'Windows Server 2016'machine, which didn't change anything

Comment: I tried the same on a Windows Server 2008 R2 System, which didn't work either. I get an entry in the access-log, but no other entry in a log.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a version of TomCat, which initializes Tomcat as a Service. This miraculously solved the problem.
I don't understand, why this solved the Problem. But it did.

So this question is answered (somehow).